# Migrating from SourceGear Vault Source Control to GitHub - Set up

Tags: github, version-control

I'm looking into migrating our existing ASP.NET projects in SourceGear Vault to Github.

The PROJECTS are PROJ1, PROJ2, PROJ3.
- where PROJ2 and PROJ3 are forked from the original PROJ1. 
- All bug fixes done in PROJ1 was always pushed and synchronized to PROJ2 and PROJ3.

The current set up in our existing Source Control is as follows:

1. PROJ1 > Webforms Project which has the BL, DAO, WebApp...etc ( all under the same solution  )
2. PROJ2 > Webforms Project and  was forked from PROJ1 ( at some point in time ~ 1 yr of work and contains mostly Front end UI changes but most back end logic and architecture is still the same ). This is the next Release which will be done within 6 months as BETA
3. PROJ3 > This is an attempt to move away from the conventional WebForms Project to  Angular with WebAPI Architecure... So reusing some of the BL and exposing them as REST Service , and having an Angular Framework Client. This is a version we will be doing may be in 1 - 2 years time.

How can I set these up in GitHub so that we can :

1. Keep pushing bug fixes discovered and fixed in PROJ1 to PROJ2 and PROJ3 ?
2. At any point in time, if a dev is assigned to work exlusively in PROJ2 or PROJ3 ( for new features ) OR can switch back to PROJ1 ( for bug fixing)

Ex: Do we create 3 Repository in GitHub? Do we create One Master Repo and Create 2 Branches (PROJ2, PROJ3)...etc How do we handle Merge between PROJECTS ( when a bug is fixed in PROJ1)..

Assumption: We will always fix in 1 and push to 2 and 3 but never backwards.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"Branches" mean generally you will merge them back to a "main" branch.

But in your case, `Project3` is a true fork, meaning it won't be merged back to `Project1`: so it should be its own repository.

`Project2` could be a branch called "`next`" (for preparing the next release) within a `Project1` GitHub repository.

Comment: Now that we are getting closer to the change in Source Control Tool to Github, Id like to pick up on this challenge....So I should have 2 Repositories - for PROJ1 (and creating a branch within it for PROJ2) so that the Master PROJ1 , PROJ2 as a Branch which eventually will be merged into one repo? Since PROJ2 is already ahead of PROJ1 ( from my original Source Control), How would i create PROJ2. Also how do I keep updating PROJ3 with changes to PROJ1 ( some core logics are replicated in PROJ3 so I have to maintain them).